# How to pick a random node from a tree

Tags: random, tree

How would one go about choosing a random element from a tree? Is it necessary to know the depth/size of the tree beforehand?

Answer (score 14):

It is not.  To choose a node uniformly at random, simply iterate through the tree in any order you like.  Let the nth node examined be the chosen one with probability 1/n.  That is, keep a record of the node you would return in a variable, and when you look at the nth node, replace the current node with the nth one with probability 1/n.  You can show by induction that this returns a node uniformly at random without needing to know how many there are beforehand.

Comment: To put a name on it: This is a well-known algorithm, known as [Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Answer (score 2):

If you've structured your leaves to be stored themselves within an index-able data type, like an array, then you can easily (pseudocode):

```
random_leaf = leaf_pile[ random( size of leaf pile ) ]
```

That's a nice, refreshing O(1) :-)

Of course, there may be holes, so you may have to iterate from there. If it's stored as a linked list, then you can iterate though.

Just providing an alternative to the obvious. It really depends on your data structure and your commonest-use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Just do for each node a random call in the range 0 up to (number of childs)-1 and select the next child after that number.

Repeat this until you are in a leaf.

Comment: This will be biased towards nodes at upper levels of the tree. For example, the probability of selecting the rootNode = 1/3 (assuming a max of 2 children). The probability of selecting the leftmost leaf node = (1/3)^k, where k = depth of the leaf node.

Comment: this is true, however, in some instances it doesn't matter but thx for pointing this out